# "Already" with Present Perfect Continuos

Tags: present-perfect

Would it be correct to say about my exploring something for a certain period of time in this manner or I'd better say it without "already" (only with Perfect Tense, not Perfect Progressive):

> I've already been studying humankind for 30 years.

Comment: **Already** makes the sentence sound strange.

Comment: @SovereignSun It would sound less strange if it was placed between have and been... As in "You should come and study humankind with us." "(But) I've already been studying humankind for 30 years."

Comment: @SteveES Yeh, it sounds better when placed there.

Comment: @SovereignSun, ok

Comment: @SteveES, I'm sorry for about that typo. I've already edited it. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only combine 'already' with 'studied', not 'been studying', says my native English brain. I apologise for not knowing the correct terms for those two tenses.

Comment: So, why does the comments above claim to be opposite?